# Error while reading image using cv2.imread() in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, numpy

I am trying to apply image processing on an image which i'm loading through `cv2.imread()` in Django's `views.py` file, but i'm getting an `AttributeError` everytime.

**Following is the hierarchy**

[image: Heirarchy]

**views.py** through which i'm trying to read **`temp321.jpg` :**

```
def process_image(request):
    url = "static/images/temp321.jpg"
    a = cv2.imread(url)
    r, c = a.shape
```

**Error** which i'm getting:

[image: Error message snapshot]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @e4c5 why is that? I was able to read the file by creating a new python file and reading the image from that file. I'm not able to read the image from `views.py` only

Comment: @e4c5 so what should i do in order to read the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that `a` is None. With `a` being the result of the call to `cv2.imread`

> If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper
>   permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an
>   empty matrix

This is from the cv2 c documentation. This translates to None in python. So the problem essentially is that your file is not being read.

The solution:
If you have setup the PROJECT_ROOT variable properly in your settings.py file

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static/images/temp321.jpg")
```

If you don't have PROJECT_ROOT setup, add to settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Note that you may still have trouble if you are doing this in production because the webserver may not be allowed to read from that directory. In that case you will need to change file system permissions

Comment: Thankyou for this! I'm still new to django, this helped me big time!

Comment: glad to have been of help. All the best for your project

Comment: Thanks mate! :D One last thing, `PROJECT_ROOT` works on local system perfectly but how to implement the same logic on server? how to access the same temp321.jpg file when this project is deployed online?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me

```
img_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,"directory/image.jpg")
```